# Getting OverflowError: math range error(trying to calculate power of a number)

Tags: python, math

I am trying to find the exact digit of the expression. which I am unable to find it. Below is the snippet code I have tried.

```
>>> math.pow(400.0,math.pow(400.0,400.0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error
```

When I have tried with numpy I was getting like:

```
>>> np.power(400.0,np.power(400.0,400.0))
>>> inf
```

But I couldnt get the exact digit. Can anyone help me out with this. It would be a great help for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That is not a duplicate @Bakuriu. I have come across a situation in my project. Your support can b grately appreciated. If you can find me the number. Thank You

Comment: The question **is** a duplicate. If you solved your problem is either because you are actually using numbers which are much smaller then what you asked, or because you changed approach. In any case, since the question you posted is *not* about what you changed *now*, it's still a dupe.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis @Bakuriu. But thats not the case with my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number you are trying to calculate has `1.735057357739408×10^1041` decimal digits (from [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%5E%28400%5E400%29)). You most certainly cannot get the exact representation for it. `inf` is as close as you are going to get.

Answer (score 0):

The number can not be represented exactly with the size allocated to store an integer. Use `sys.maxint` to see your max int, there is also long, on a 62bit box you can see as follows

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> type(2**63)
<type 'long'>
>>> type(2**62)
<type 'int'>
>>> sys.maxint - (2**63 - 1) == 0
True
```

Answer (score -2):

You can have your exact digit here : [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400^%28400^400%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%5E%28400%5E400%29)

Comment: Since the number has inconceivably many more digits than the observable universe has atoms, Wolfram does *not* give an exact decimal representation.

Comment: That page does not provide the exact digits, because it's not possible.